# Find a particular path for Vanishing the integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, contour-integration

Is it possible to find a path from P to Q such that:

$$\int_C xy^2dx+ydy=0;\, P=(0,0)\, \text{and}\, Q=(1,1)$$

$$\int_C \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}=0;\, P(-1,0)\, \text{and}\, Q=(1,0)$$

I've asked before for the possibility to find a path for vanishing in general, but now I want to know if there's a path for that particular points, Hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know Green's Theorem? If so, you should be able to prove that the second one is impossible.

The first one is possible, but it's not so easy. Here's a hint. Take an easy path, say the straight line from $P$ to $Q$. Then follow that path by the path that goes around a rectangle from $(1,1)$ to $(a,1)$ to $(a,b)$ to $(1,b)$ and back to $(1,1)$ so that that integral cancels out the first one. (Green's Theorem will help here, too.)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is possible: Let $A=(-a,1)$ and $C=\vec{PA}+\vec{AQ}$. (I think $a=2$.)

The second one is not: $\int_Cd(\arctan(y/x))=0$.